# Is it possible to setup two PHP projects with the same base url using Alias/Rewrite rules?

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, centos

I'm working on rewriting a `CMSMadeSimple` project in `CakePHP` and am wondering if the following is possible:

I have two projects on separate vhosts.  I currently have them on different ports and all is well:

```
/var/www/project1 -> www.example.com

/var/www/project2 -> www.example.com:8080
```

Where `project1` is CMSMS and project 2 is CakePHP. The goal is to get them on the same port and use project 2 for certain subdirectories.

For each subdirectory there are pages specific to that role.  This would be the desired behavior:

Project 2:

```
www.example.com/cat/*

www.example.com/dog/*
```

Project 1:

```
www.example.com

www.example.com/* (except cat and dog)
```

I'm hoping this is possible using some combitionation of alias and rewriting.  I've got it figured out if one project is in a subdirectory

```
(Exmaple: Project2 -> www.example.com/pets/cat),
```

But I'm having trouble when they share the same base. Part of the issue is that I can't really use `RewriteBase` in the `.htaccess` file for the CakePHP project because without the subdirectory ("pets" in the example) it's variable.

The projects are running on a Centos server using Apache.

**Edit for anyone with a similar issue:**

The solution I ended up going with was to alias the subdirectories I wanted to go to project 2 in the vhost for project 1.  Then, in the .htaccess file for project 2 I used RewriteBase to the project 2 directory to make sure the paths resolved correctly.

Comment: Why not use Name Based Virtual hosts and then create subdomains

Comment: I agree that we could definitely do that, but the preference is to try and have URL's appear as I mentioned.  If it ends up being a situation where a subdomain has to be used we could go that way, but I figured it was worth asking around first.